# Center Infobox Google Maps V3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, center, infobox

Been searching for days and read every thread here on Stack with the words Google Maps and Center but cannot find anything that comes close to the problem.

I'm putting together a Google Map that has multiple markers.
The map is locked so that it cannot be moved or zoomed.
When you click a marker the infobox opens and the map is locked with disableAutoPan: true
These things work fine.

However, the problem occurs with markers near the edge of the map and the infoboxes being off screen.
I have tried for days to try and remedy this including pixelOffset: and position: but so far nothing has worked.

So my question, is it possible to position an infobox bang in the center of the screen and if so how?
Example [Example of what I am trying to achieve](http://www.cvc1659.co.za/members/)

Sorry for the long-windedness

Answer (score 0):

The answers to another SO question, [Border detection on infoboxes so they don't get drawn off the map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10553007/border-dectection-on-infoboxes-so-they-dont-get-draw-off-the-map), may help you. There is even an example mentioned ([SmartInfoWindow Demo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10553007/border-dectection-on-infoboxes-so-they-dont-get-draw-off-the-map)) that shows a working demo of infoboxes that never fall off the screen.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I did see this whilst searching on SO. Tried it but this does not allow me to center the infobox on the screen.